# Is there any particular reason this type is not a generalized DFA? And if so, what is it really?

Tags: scala, haskell, automata

I'm putting together a library of fundamental structures in Scala for use in either production or for personal study.  I'm focusing on clear descriptions of said structures in either type theory, cat theory, set theory. One of the types,

```
abstract case class Fold[A, B]() {
  type I
  def trans: I => A => I
  def start: I
  def output: I => B

  def cojoin: Fold[A, Fold[A, B]] 
  def copoint: B    
  def dimap[Z, C](f: Z => A, g: B => C): Fold[Z, C]
 }
```

which is (I'm fairly certain) isomorphic to,
(credit: http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/composable-streaming-folds.html)

```
abstract case class Fold'[A, B]() {
  type W
  def MonW: Monoid[W]
  def tally: A => W
  def summerize: W => B
}
```

One of the types to me greatly resembles a DFA, and in https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/cellular-automata/part-2
Mr. Kmett essentially says as much.  My question is what is this type if *not* a DFA?

Answer (score 7):

This type does not represent a DFA because it is too general. Specifically, the `I` type may be able to take on infinitely many values. If you make `I` a sequence of some kind (or, better, two of them) paired with something representing finite state, you can easily simulate a Turing machine directly.